Unexpected token 'export' when using MUI X Charts in a Remix app
I am trying to use MUI X Charts in a shopify remix app, but am unable to render a chart due to the following error:
export * from './constants';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'


Not quite sure how to go about handling this. Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

I experienced this error in a Remix app and solved it using this instead.
import {Button} from '@mui/material';

